# Aggregate function in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:  TITLE and BACKGROUND

BACKGROUND has a foreign key into TITLE so I'm trying to write a query that will return any TITLE rows that have more than one matching BACKGROUND.

```
SELECT T.ID
  FROM TITLE T, BACKGROUND B
 WHERE T.ID = B.TITLE_ID
   AND /* there are multiple matching background rows */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t.id
  from title t
 where exists (select * 
                 from background b
                where b.title_id = t.id
                having count(*) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried.....

```
select T.ID from (
    SELECT T.ID,B.TITLE_ID, count(*)
      FROM TITLE T, BACKGROUND B
      WHERE T.ID = B.TITLE_ID
      group by T.ID,B.TITLE_ID
      having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Rajesh, construct is incorrect in your SQL. You cannot group by B.TITLE_ID unless you have B.TITLE_ID is in the select list.

Comment: Thanks Mevdiven, Corrected it now. Your query makes more sense though. +1

Comment: I remember that it was possible to group by attributes not in the select list with oracle, and sometimes missed it with postgresql. I missed it on other RDBMS too.